# How can I get my custom attribute of a column from jquery datatables on draw.dt function?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a custom datatable extends jquery datatables. I have a custom attribute in column which name is like `dataType`. How can I get value of this custom attribute on `draw.dt` event of jquery datatable?

**Here is my custom datatable extension;**

```
$.fn.customDataTable = function (options) {    
var dataTable = table.DataTable({
    order: options.order,
    rowId: options.rowId,
    ajax: options.ajax,
    columns: options.columns,
    paging: paging,
    serverSide: true,
    processing: true,
    responsive: true,
    language: {
        url: '/Features/Shared/Component/DataTable/Localization/datatables_tr.json',
        oPaginate: {
            sFirst: '<i class="fas fa-step-backward"></i>',
            sPrevious: '<i class="fas fa-caret-left"></i>',
            sNext: '<i class="fas fa-caret-right"></i>',
            sLast: '<i class="fas fa-step-forward"></i>'
        },
        sProcessing: `<i class="fas fa-circle-notch fa-spin fa-3x"></i>`,
    },
    initComplete: function (settings) {
        ...
        ...
    },
    drawCallback: function () {
        ...
        ...
    }
});

dataTable.on('draw.dt', function (e) {
    ...
    //Here is where I want to get my custom attribute of a column
    ...
});

return dataTable;
}
```

**Here is an example usage of my custom datatable;**

```
$('#tbl_Company').customDataTable({
    order: [[0, 'desc']],
    rowId: 'id',
    ajax: {
        url: '/Company/GetCompanies',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json'
    },
    columns: [
        {
            data: 'createdAt',
            name: 'CreatedAt',
            orderable: false,
            defaultContent: '',
            dataType: 'date'
        }
    ]
});
```

Comment: You mean you want to get the custom attribute of the column's `thead th` (header) or its `tbody td`?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this as below

```
dataTable.on('draw.dt', function (e) {

    dataTable.cells().every(function (r, c) {

        var dataType = dataTable.settings()[0].aoColumns[c].dataType;
        if (dataType) {
            ...
        }
    });
});
```

thank you @ruleboy21